# How to index complex xml in apache SOLR?

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene

I have an xml which looks something like as below:

```
 <info>
  <metadata>
    <topic>ww2</topic>
    <subject>history</subject>
  </metadata>
  <information>
    <catalogs isreq="1" schema_version="1.0.0" >
      <catalog group="1" part_of_sub="N">
        <country>FR</country>
        <year format="yyyy-mm-dd">1885-11-02</year >
        </category_definition>
     <catalog group="1" part_of_sub="Y">
        <country>GR</country>
        <year format="yyyy-mm-dd">1885-11-02</year >
        </category_definition>
        </catalogs>
         </information>
     </info>
```

I want to index this xml without flattening it. I did saw  `childDocuments` getting used for indexing complex json [referring to this http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/ ]. I am not really sure how to use this for xml document?

Comment: So how do you want to query it?

Comment: I would like to query solr something like country:"FR" and it should return me all the documents which would satisfy the criteria.

Comment: And what would a document be in that context? The whole `<info>` structure?

Comment: What is it that you think 'flattening' means in that context and what exactly do you want to avoid about it?

Comment: FWIW avoid child documents - see my answer for another question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244434/277023

Comment: To answer @MatsLindh , yes you are correct to think that. I would like to index entire <info> xml.

Comment: To Answer @Harald, when I say flattening, all the child and respective parent elements of the xml becomes a simple elements of <doc> of SOLR. Something like below : <code> <field name="id">1</field>
        <field name="solr_record_type">1</field>
        <field name="title">Fabulous Book</field>
        <field name="author">Angelo Author</field></code>

Comment: @kellyfj Thanks for pointing this out. It is really helpful.